# import workbox from local v5 in webpack-plugin

Tags: workbox, sw-precache, workbox-webpack-plugin

As we now in version 5 of workbox, the `importWorkboxFrom` config is removed, but if we are using `injectManifest` how we should import workbox localy? 
Is the only way in using `importScripts` with `https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.0.0/workbox-sw.js`?

docs says that `generateSW` uses locally import by default but what about `injectManifest`?
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v4#build_tool_option_overhaul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Workbox v5 in `InjectManifest` mode, then you should consume the Workbox runtime libraries ES modules, and allow `webpack` to compile/bundle them into the final output `swDest` file. You don't need to use `importScripts()` or the CDN anymore.

There more info about making this change at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers#moving_from_importscripts_to_module_imports

Comment: thanks, In this way where to put custom importScripts? webpack does compile the workbox-sw and injectManifest will add some data on it. As the `importScripts` property removed in v5 from inject manifest, where we should add custom `importScripts`?

Comment: In v5 in `InjectManifest` mode, you can either include the logic you'd otherwise put into an imported script directly in you top-level `swSrc` file, or alternatively, write `importScripts('path/to/imports.js')` in your `swSrc` file. You have complete control over the contents of your service worker.

Comment: @JeffPosnick I had below config earlier, 
`new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({ importWorkboxFrom: 'cdn', // some other configs })`
So now after updating to v7, should I completely remove the `importWorkboxFrom` property?